# Approximation the sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (c+n)^{k-1} e^{-\frac{(c+n)^k}{2*a}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, approximation

I would like to find lower and upper bounds on the following sum

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (c+n)^{k-1} e^{-\frac{(c+n)^k}{2*a}}
\end{align}
where $c,a>0$ and $k>1$.

Note that if we could approximate this sum with an integral then 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (c+n)^{k-1} e^{-\frac{(c+n)^k}{2*a}} \approx \int _{n=0}^\infty (c+n)^{k-1} e^{-\frac{(c+n)^k}{2*a}} dn=  -\frac{2 a}{k} e^{-\frac{(c+n)^k}{2*a}} |_0^\infty=\frac{2 a}{k} e^{-\frac{c^k}{2*a}}
\end{align}

then one might guess that the bounds are 
\begin{align}
\frac{2 a}{k} e^{-\frac{c^k}{2*a}}+c_1 \le\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (c+n)^{k-1} e^{-\frac{(c+n)^k}{2*a}} \le \frac{2 a}{k} e^{-\frac{c^k}{2*a}}+c_2
\end{align}

My question is how can this be done or is there a better method  to give lower and upper bounds?

I also know that there are bounds of the form
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f(x) dx \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) \le f(0) + \int_0^\infty f(x) dx
\end{align}

but they only hold if $f(x)$ is monotone decreasing which is not the case here.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (c+n)^{k-1} e^{-\frac{(c+n)^k}{2a}}= -\frac{2a}{k} \frac{\partial}{\partial c} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  e^{-\frac{(c+n)^k}{2a}} $$ Might be useful, since the latter sum converges much faster